# How can I create a regular express pattern which has 30 charater fixed length？

Tags: asp.net, regex

How can I create a regular express pattern which has 30 charater fixed length, but the charater in the pattern could be less than 30 and pad with spaces.

For example, I want to enter these kind of values:

Jack Howe

Katherine Joe

Ken's Workstation

They all should be left justify and pad with spaces to meet 30 fixed length character.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use a regular expression for this? the code below will do it just fine:

```
string myString = "Test";
myString = myString.PadRight(30, ' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you're trying to do is ensure a fixed character length, then regex is the wrong tool for this. Use string manipulation:

```
return str.Trim().PadRight(30);
```

Comment: +1 trim before padding to guarantee left justify is a good idea